# Nuitka | FATAL: Error, must specify existing source data directory

Tags: python, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a python script to project **EXE** using **Nuitka** My project structure is as follows:

```
Myproject
|  
├─ images
│  ├─ image1.png
│  ├─ image2.png
│  ├─ image3.png
|  
|  
├─ requirements.txt
|  
|  
├─ scapper.py
|  
├─ GUI.py
|  
|  
|  
└─ Utils
   └─ chromedriver.exe
```

My problem is when compiling the python using the following command:

`python -m nuitka --standalone --onefile --show-progress --windows-disable-console --include-data-dir=D:\VS-CODE\XCALLY\images=images --include-data-dir=D:\VS-CODE\XCALLY\Utils=Utils --enable-plugin=tk-inter GUI.py`

The .exe file works on the same directory with the image, but if I move it to another directory, I have to copy the image folder as well in order to keep it working.

**I need help to figure out how to include the image folder inside the EXE file, so I can run it automatically.**

I've already tried to miss arroung the compiling script like :

`python -m nuitka --standalone --onefile --show-progress --windows-disable-console --include-data-dir=images=images\* --include-data-dir=Utils=Utils\* --enable-plugin=tk-inter GUI.py`

output :

`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'GUI.dist\\images\\*'`

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved, just for future reference, Here's how I fixed it:

Create a function that returns the absolute path to the files inside /images folder

```
def resource_path(filename):
    # Get the absolute path of the directory containing the executable
    exe_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Construct the path to the image file
    image_path = os.path.join(exe_dir, filename)

    # Return the image path
    return image_path
```

Since python considers " \ " as escape characters in the string I've changed the path on my code for images to something like this:

```
image1 = resource_path(r"images\\images1.png"))
```

and for compiling the script I've used the below options:

```
nuitka --onefile  --windows-disable-console --include-data-dir=./images/=images --include-data-dir=./Utils/=Utils --enable-plugin=tk-inter GUI.py
```